# Understanding Monad CountMe's bind through equational reasoning

Tags: haskell, monads

This question arises from the section "Bad monads and their denizens" of section 18.5 "Monad laws" of the book "Haskell Programming from first principles".

```
data CountMe a =
  CountMe Integer a
  deriving (Eq, Show)
instance Functor CountMe where
  fmap f (CountMe i a) =
    CountMe i (f a)
instance Applicative CountMe where
  pure = CountMe 0
  CountMe n f <*> CountMe n' a =
    CountMe (n + n') (f a)
instance Monad CountMe where
  return = pure
  CountMe n a >>= f =
    let CountMe n' b = f a
    in CountMe (n + n') b
```

I have some problems understanding how Monad CountMe's bind works using equational reasoning:

`CountMe (n + n') b`
becomes
`CountMe n b + CountMe n' b`
becomes
`CountMe n b + f a`

Is this correct?  If so, what does `CountMe n b` become?

If equational reasoning cannot be done, how should I understand how this works?

```
  CountMe n a >>= f =
    let CountMe n' b = f a
    in CountMe (n + n') b
```

Comment: `CountMe (n + n') b = CountMe n b + CountMe n' b` looks wrong - there is no `+` for your `CountMe` as far as I can see . I also have trouble seeing what you try to expand/prove (`bind`/`>>=` does not seem to be involved in what you write at all)

Comment: Is the pattern-matching here causing some confusion for you? This is effectively the same as `bind (n, a) f = let { (n', b) = f a } in (n + n', b)`, or `bind p1 f = let { p2 = f (snd p1) } in (fst p1 + fst p2, snd p2)`—are those any clearer? That is, a value of type `CountMe a` is equivalent to a pair `(Integer, a)`, and the bind implementation in the `Monad` instance calls a function `f` on such a pair `p1`, and combines `p1` with the result of that function `p2`, using summation for the first component, and the latter pair’s second component.

Comment: @JonPurdy, Thanks, your answer helped a little.  I think the most explanatory answer is from @DavidFletcher, because he provided an example that dissociates to a certain extent `myfunc` from `x`.  Before I thought through his answer, my mind was trying to do `CountMe n b = f a`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to understand the definition is to come up with some
arguments for bind and try applying it to them.  (I think this still
counts as equational reasoning, just a simple form of it where all we
do is reduce expressions.)

The type of `>>=` specialised to CountMe is

```
CountMe a -> (a -> CountMe b) -> CountMe b
```

Let's try with `a` being `Int` and `b` being `Bool`.

```
CountMe Int -> (Int -> CountMe Bool) -> CountMe Bool
```

For the first argument we want a `CountMe Int`, let's call it x and
say:

```
x = CountMe 42 4
```

We need a function for our second argument so I'll just write one:

```
myfunc :: Int -> CountMe Bool
myfunc i = CountMe 37 (even i)
```

(`even` is the function from Prelude for checking if numbers are
even.)

Now we can evaluate `x >>= myfunc` and see what happens:

```
  x >>= myfunc
=                                         definition of x
  CountMe 42 4 >>= myfunc
=                                         definition of >>=,
                                          substituting in n=42, a=4, f=myfunc
  let CountMe n' b = myfunc 4
  in CountMe (42 + n') b
=                                         definition of myfunc with i=4
  let CountMe n' b = CountMe 37 (even 4)
  in CountMe (42 + n') b
=                                         definition of even
  let CountMe n' b = CountMe 37 True
  in CountMe (42 + n') b
=                                         pattern match gives n'=37, b=True,
                                          substitute these into body of let
  CountMe (42 + 37) True
=                                         arithmetic
  CountMe 79 True
```

So that's one example of what it does.  It you want to try more
examples you might need to to write other functions to use as the
second argument to bind.  (`pure` could fit there as one possibility I
suppose.  I don't know if you've been given any other functions of the
right shape.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm now wondering if there are any explanations from outside equational reasoning that would explain this CountMe Monad better..

Answer (score 6):

Equational reasoning is useful when you're trying to prove that a function satisfies some law, or that two expressions compute the same value, or some similar hypothesis. Equational reasoning can't synthesise an understanding of how a function works — you have to start with a plan. If you just want to figure out what a function does, the best way to do that is to read the code!

For an example of the sort of thing that equational reasoning *can* do, let's suppose we wanted to ascertain whether `CountMe`'s `Monad` instance satisfies the "left identity" law,

```
return x >>= f = f x
```

Here's the plan. We'll start with the expression `return x >>= f` and try to transform it into `f x` using equational reasoning.

```
return x >>= f
CountMe 0 x >>= f                             -- definition of return
let CountMe n' b = f x in CountMe (0 + n') b  -- definition of (>>=)
let CountMe n' b = f x in CountMe n' b        -- 0 + n' = n'
f x                                           -- let pat = x in pat <-> x
```

For what it's worth, your `CountMe` monad is an example of a [`Writer` monad](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#writer) (specifically, `Writer (Sum Integer)`). Briefly, `Writer` computations build up a monoidal "log" value while computing a result; in this case, the "log" value is an `Integer` and the notion of "building up" is addition.

Comment: Thanks, to be honest, I'm also trying to think about how to write such a function when I try to understand the function.  Right now, I can't figure out the function enough to write something similar..

Answer (score 5):

> `CountMe (n + n') b` becomes `CountMe n b + CountMe n' b`

Nope, this very first step already isn't correct. There isn't really any evaluation step you can take here without knowing something more about `n`, `n'`, or `b`.

For example, if you knew `n=5` and `n'=7`, say, then you could say `CountMe (5+7) b` becomes `CountMe 12 b`. Or, if you knew `b=const "abc" True`, then you could say `CountMe (n + n') (const "abc" True)` becomes `CountMe (n + n') "abc"`. But as it stands, there simply isn't a next evaluation step you can take.

Of course, there are lots of "unevaluation" equalities you could write, like

```
CountMe (n + n') b = CountMe (0 + n + n') b
CountMe (n + n') b = CountMe (n + n') (if True then b else "mugwump")
```

and so on, but it's not clear that any of them are particularly exciting or useful equations for understanding what bind does.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question.  My main problem is understanding how the bind works in the Monad CountMe, which involves let and in...

Comment: Would you like help understanding what `let ... in` does?